# Como puedo convertirlo este consulta de SQL a LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
 SELECT STUFF((
   SELECT  ','+EXC_Nombre

   FROM Bloqueos as B, Excursiones as E
   Where B.BloqueosId = 3 and E.ExcursionesId IN (
   SELECT 
  [BLE_ExcursionId]      
 FROM [BloqueoExcursions]
 Where BLE_BloqueoID = 3)    
   FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1, '')
```

#### Esta es mi base de datos

Tabla: Excursiones

```
ExcursionesId | EXC_Nombre
--------------|----------
2             | Tangol
3             | estadioo
4             | Visita
5             | Pampa
7             | aa
8             | bbb
21            | cc
22            | mmm
```

Tabla: Bloqueos

```
BloqueosId
----------
69
70
71
```

Tabla:BloqueoExcursion

```
BloqueoExcursionId | BLE_ExcurionId | BLE_BloqueoId 
-------------------|----------------|--------------
11                 | 8              | 1 
12                 | 3              | 1 
17                 | 4              | 66
20                 | 2              | 3
21                 | 7              | 3
22                 | 3              | 67 
23                 | 8              | 67
```

Comment: Michael, veo que varias de tus preguntas fueron cerradas con anterioridad, es importante que leas [ask] para que tengas información acerca de como realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida 
en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas, saludos!

Comment: Podrías [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/103806/edit) e incluir la definición de tus clases. Comprendo que estás concatenando todo los registros de la columna `EXC_Nombre`, ¿Pertenece a la tabla `Excursiones`?.  Sería bueno que revises: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Asi es estoy concatenando de tres tablas el EXC_Nombre esta en la tabla excursiones ; este mi consulta si me funciona en sql. solo quiero convertirlo   a LINQ

Answer (score 1):

Según las tablas adjuntas -y los resultados que entiendo esperas- yo escribiría la consulta sql de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT 
STUFF((SELECT ',' + e.EXC_Nombre 
   FROM BloqueoExcursion be 
      INNER JOIN Excursiones e ON be.BLE_ExcurionId = e.ExcursionesId
   WHERE be.BLE_BloqueoId = 3 GROUP BY e.EXC_Nombre FOR XML PATH('')),1,1, 
'');
GO
```

Consulta Linq:

```
string _EXC_Nombre = string.Join(",",
        (from be in dbContext.BloqueoExcursion
         join e in dbContext.Excursiones on be.BLE_ExcurionId equals e.ExcursionesId
         select e.EXC_Nombre).Distinct().ToArray());
```

Comment: Buenísimo tu aporte gracias, solo una consulta al ejecutar la consulta Linq me sale este error: error  compiling Expression  invalid expression term 'string.  Estoy comprobando con Linqer

Comment: Imagino que se debe a que el código adjunto lleva consigo instrucciones que pertenecen al marco de trabajo de .NET como el método Join() o ToArray() y que probablemente Linqer no logra "entender". Te recomiendo que pruebes el código adjunto directamente desde tu aplicación.

Comment: ¿Como Puedo guardar from en una variable ? string _EXC_Nombre = string.Join(",",
            (from be in contexto.BloqueoExcursion
             join e in contexto.Excursion on be.BLE_ExcursionId
             equals e.ExcursionesId
             select e.EXC_Nombre).Distinct().ToArray());     

            var lComBloquepsNom = query.ToList();
            foreach (var datos in lComBloquepsNom)
            {
                vCOMBLO_Comprar.BloqueosId = datos.ExcursionesId;
                vCOMBLO_Comprar.ciudadori = datos.EXC_Nombre;
            }
            return vCOMBLO_Comprar;

Comment: Porque hacer este codigo necesita declarar query en el from